# Why set connection.setAutoCommit(false) , insert, then rollback, still insert data to database?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

My environment: Windows 11 x64, Oracle database 21c Express edtion, Java /JDK 19,IntelliJ IDEA 2023.x . I have

```sql
select banner from v$version;
-- Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class VyInsert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "system", "12345678")) {

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                System.out.println("Connected to the database.");
                String query = "insert into SYSTEM.CUSTOMER (ID, NAME, EMAIL, CREATED_DATE) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                preparedStatement.setInt(1, 17);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, "Nguyen Thu Hang23");
                preparedStatement.setString(3, "anhtrangmuathu32@gmail.com");
                preparedStatement.setObject(4, LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/Montreal")));
                // preparedStatement.setObject(4, LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh")));
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                // connection.commit();
                //connection.setAutoCommit(true);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection.");
            }

        } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", sqlException.getSQLState(), sqlException.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Why set connection.setAutoCommit(false) , insert, then rollback, still insert data to database?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the `if (connection != null)` is entirely unneeded as `DriverManager.getConnection` will never return `null`. It will always either return a connection, or it will throw a SQLException.

Comment: As I said, either you have a valid connection, or an exception was thrown (which ends up in the `catch (SQLException sqlException)` block).

Comment: I understand it now, thank you for your catch. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code never calls `connection.rollback()`, and the Oracle JDBC driver (or Oracle itself) is one of the few out there which **commit** an open transaction when you close the connection. So, once your application exits the try-with-resource block, the changes made by your application have already been committed.

Know that most JDBC drivers (or DBMSes) will rollback active transactions on connection close, and Oracle is an exception in this regard.

In addition, your screenshot shows you calling rollback in an unrelated application. That `rollback` statement can only roll back *that* transaction of *that* application and its connection, not the transaction of an entirely different application and its connection (especially not when that connection is already closed and its transaction committed).

Comment: Can you give me an example for commit not finish? I want to experience it.

Comment: @RaphaëlColantonio I have trouble understanding what you mean. If you mean how to prevent the change from being committed, add `connection.rollback()` to the end of your code (*before* the end of the try-with-resources), optionally in the `finally` block of a `try` wrapping your code.

Comment: By the way, You can give me sample not use try-with-resource, then the program cannot insert data to database with autocommit = false. I am looking this example from you. (Your answer is enough for the question, but I want learn more)

Comment: @RaphaëlColantonio That is not how it works, even without try-with-resources, the connection will be closed eventually (either by the garbage collector, or the exit of the application), and then probably still result in a commit (though I'm not sure if the commit is specific to the Oracle JDBC driver or Oracle itself, so it might exhibit different behaviour in that edge case, but that is really not something you should rely on)